# Syntax error when defining function

Tags: python, function, syntax

I've got a syntax error when defining this function.

```
def questionfilehandler("filename.txt"):
    with open("filename.txt", "r") as file:
        print(file.read)
        return input()
        file.close()
```

I've looked up the syntax, and it all appears to be correct.
[This is the error message I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRzs9.png)
[And this is the code with the error highlighted by IDLE.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xpkvf.png)

Thanks to everyone who reads and tries to answer this. Your time is greatly appreciated =).

Comment: You haven't indented properly.

Comment: Is the code you show a direct copy-paste of the actual code? With the indentation as shown?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in writing it on the website. The indents are correct in the real program. I've fixed them now.

Comment: Your parameter for the function can't be written as a string.

Comment: One other thing to know is that when using the context handler `with open(my_file ...` you don't need to call `my_file.close()` at the end. It's automatically handled by the `with` statement!

Answer (score 9):

Assuming your indentation gets fixed, which is obvious... you cannot call a string directly as a function argument. You need a variable:

```
def questionfilehandler(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        print(file.read())
        return input()
        # file.close() - not needed
```

Then... you can call the function with a string as its argument:

```
questionfilehandler("filename.txt")
```

Comment: @ZaurNasibov - fixed, and commented out file.close()

Comment: @Bob14 - please consider accepting this answer if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
def questionfilehandler(filename = "data.txt"): # filename has default value so it will take your input if you provide with function call.
    with open(filename) as filedata:
        # print(file.read()) # no need for this method as all work done by "open()".
        for data in filedata:
            print data

questionfilehandler() # You can pass file name if you want to else keep the default.
```

No need of filename.close() as "with" operator handles it automatically.